# WSO2 API Manager 2.0 User Class extension

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We've deployed WSO2 API Manager 2.0 and are very happy with it.

Although, we've been looking in the documentation if it is possible to add a field to the user profile but haven't found anything yet, is this at all possible? Also, if this is possible can we show the field somewhere on the frontend? Or better yet, is it possible to send it to a backend webservice?

Our problem is that we have a backend with users that have a token, but we didn't want to send that token to the API Manager, we want it to be added without worrying the user. Is this at all possible? We know about sequence mediation and this can probably be achieved with it, the only complication is where we store the user token, for each user.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce new user attributes to user profiles. APIM uses WSO2 identity server features internally. So you can refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Adding+Claim+Mapping).

If you enabled `Supported by Default` property, it will be shown in user profile.

You can use JWT to send user claims to backend. You can find [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT).

Last part is not much clear to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation shared, I'll look into it. The last part refers to sending the user token to the backend API registered in APIM. We want to add it as an HTTP request header without the user knowing it.

Comment: If that token is common to all users, that can be achieved easily. APIM supports that. If you need per user tokens, you need to write a custom handler. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Writing+Custom+Handlers
You can do anything within the handler. for eg. calling another service, querying a db, reading a file etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and do a wrap-up afterwards. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, just finished writing my handler. It works really well, even with the psql database.

Comment: awesome.. glad to hear that. :)